# Windows 8.1 doesn't appear in grub menu

Tags: windows

My windows 8.1 doesn't appear in grub.  Do I need to uninstall everything?

I really need Windows 8.1 to be accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Before uninstalling Ubuntu (along with GRUB), try using [boot-repair](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/). You can get it in 2 ways, on a live CD and on Ubuntu and probably some other Linux distros:

1st option:

[get a CD including Boot-Repair here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/)

boot the CD and choose recommended repair

2nd option:

open a new Terminal, then type:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update`

Press Enter and then type:

`sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)`

Press Enter

type `boot-repair` into Terminal and choose Recommended repair

[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

If that doesn't work out, [get GParted Live CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) and delete partition(s) on which Ubuntu is installed (look for ext4 and swap). You can then use that empty space to form new partitions or extend existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that the boot loader doesn't recognize windows system after installing linux . try this steps

1.boot a live cd win 7 or 8

2.turn on windowsrecovery mode

3.a window will open to you from it choose the second choice

4.choose command prompt

5.type this command `bootrec/fixmbr`if it doesn't work try this `bootrec/?`

6.restart your computer

tell me what will happen